# FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat not the same as System Locale

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm getting current format settings by doing:

```
 _FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale);
```

My system short date format is `dd.MM.yyyy` but `_FormatSettings.shorDateFormat` is `dd/MM/yyyy`. Should I replace slashes with `FormatSettings` date separator or I am not aware of something else?

I'm using Windows 10 with latest updates.

My actual short date format is:

[image: Actual locale short date format]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should not replace the slashes in `TFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`. That could cripple the date formulation.

The '/' character in `TFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat` is a **placeholder for the actual date separator character** (`TFormatSettings.DateSeparator`), that will be inserted during formulation of a date string.

Ref.

`procedure DateTimeToString(var Result: string; const Format: string;
  DateTime: TDateTime; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings);`

in System.SysUtils

Comment: Should ShortDateFormat have year string from locale too? It gives me yyyy but my locale is set to rrrr.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are saying. Where exactly and in what context do you see 'rrrr'? Also, what is your actual locale?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the language in your edit. I repeat: **In what context do you use 'rrrr'?** Delphi's string formatting routines do not recognize the letter 'r' as a valid format character. I see that it might be related to certain data bases. But how is that related to your Delphi code? Please expand your question with a real example.

Comment: My short date format in system is: dd.MM.rrrr, i.e. rrrr -> yyyy. I though that format settings will be based on system locale strings.

Comment: Use 'dd.MM.yyyy' in your Delphi code. Just of curiosity, which country/language has that date format. I looked for it but did not find any reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw. it is Polish.

Comment: Looks like Windows localized the display of the format string itself. Makes it confusing from a programming perspective but probably better for the user.